# What exactly is added in Java language levels 7.0 and 8.0?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just noticed the option to select Java Language Levels 7.0 and 8.0 in IntelliJ (under Project Settings).

Where can I find a concise description of what these enable? Level 7.0 is stated to enable "Dimonds" (what is this?), Strings in switches (cool!), and "etc..." ?

Level 8.0 has "Type Annotations", which I don't know of.

Do I have to use the appropriate JDK to setup a higher level? IntelliJ doesn't seem to mind me setting Language Level 7.0 and JDK 1.6.

Comment: As Java 7 haven't been released and Java 8 has even been start AFAIK, what they contain could change.

Answer (score 1):

some info here - http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/java7/

Answer (score 0):

If you are up to some reading, here are links for the official JSRs (Java Specification Requests).

[JSR 336](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336) - Java SE 7

[JSR 337](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337) - Java SE 8

They contain links to further JSRs that are incorporated in them.

Answer (score 0):

Project Coin has some good features:

[Features in Project Coin](http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2012/05/02/whats-new-in-java-7-features-as-part-of-project-coin/)